# Hibernate HQL: using JOIN to eagerly load child entities?

Tags: hibernate, hql

I found this HQL query that I am trying to make sense of. The comment says the `LEFT JOIN` causes Hibernate to eagerly load the associated entities in the child table, and the `DISTINCT` modifier is needed to filter out duplicate parent entities in the result set. Do these comments make sense? I have not seen a join used this way before.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p FROM Parent AS p
LEFT JOIN p.children AS c
WHERE p.state = 1
ORDER BY p.modified
```

Note `c` is not used in the `WHERE` or `ORDER BY` clauses.

It seems it would be safe to replace this query with the simpler:

```
SELECT p FROM Parent AS p
WHERE p.state = 1
ORDER BY p.modified
```

But I am not sure if there is a *good reason* the original query was written as is.

Answer (score 3):

According to Hibernate documentation:

> A "fetch" join allows associations or collections of values to be initialized along with their parent objects using a single select. This is particularly useful in the case of a collection. It effectively overrides the outer join and lazy declarations of the mapping file for associations and collections.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

So it's only the "fetch" join that causes the referred collections to load. In your case, you don't have a "fetch" join, so I don't think the collection of children will be loaded via this query.

In other words, yes, you could replace the query with the second one.